# MySQL 5.6 takes long time to connect, even with the "MySQL 5.6 Command Line Client"

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance, connection-timeout

I have had MySQL 5.6.16 and was working perfect suddenly the MySQL connection become so slow to connect (20 - 21 seconds) I have removed it completely even with the data tables and downloaded and installed ver. 5.6.19 with a fresh and new installation, but this didn't fix the long time connection EVEN with the MySQL Command Line Client it takes 20 seconds to return the "mysql>".

Also any web-based php code with mysql query connection takes 20 sec to get the data page.

I also tried enabling skip_name_resolve / connect_timeout = 10 / wait_timeout = 50 but non of this did anything.

I have:
Windows 7 Home Premium SP1 x64
MySQL 5.6.19-enterprise-commercial-advanced
Apache 2.4.9 (Win64) OpenSSL 1.0.1f
PHP 5.5.10
MySQL Global Status: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gz44pvtomwbncog/MYSQL_GLOBAL_STATUS.txt

Comment: Are you connecting to a local database or a database on a remote host? If remote, DNS lookups from client to server may be your problem.

Comment: try adding to my.cnf, in section mysqld: [skip-name-resolve](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-name-resolve).

Comment: I am connecting to a local database

Comment: I have already tried skip_name_resolve and it didn't make any change

Answer (score 0):

Thanks anyway, I have figured out that this issue because of the windows, I have used a repair tool: "Tweaking.com - Windows Repair" and it fixed this issue...