# mysql initial connection suddenly taking too long

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql 5.5.16 on windows 2008 R2 virtual server, and remotely connecting to it using C# and locally connecting to it using PHP.  Its been working fine for past 5 month but suddenly today I started getting this error in C# code:

> Timeout expired: The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

Also if I use HeidiSQL, its also talking more than a minute to connect, however, once connected, the queries are running without any delay.  I have tried adding `skip_name_resolve` in the server's `my.ini` file but no use.

Comment: Try to restart the database maybe something crashed.

Comment: I have restarted the database as well as the whole server

Comment: Do you connect using an ip or a domain name?

Comment: I connect using IP

Comment: This user had the same problem I think: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25223266/mysql-5-6-takes-long-time-to-connect-even-with-the-mysql-5-6-command-line-clie

Comment: I have reviewed it, but its not recommended for windows server, I am using virtual windows server 2008 R2.